# Redirect users to their sites after login

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1.1CE.

In my portal I have 3 Communities (Sites)

My question is, how can I redirect the users to the appropriate site (i.e. the site which they have been assigned by the admin) after login to the portal?

If single site is there for every users, then its easy to redirect via portal settings.

Comment: Based on what do you want to redirect your users ? What do you call "the corresponding site" ? Did you mean "the appropriate site" ?

Comment: based on the site assigned by the admin,users redirected to appropriate site

Comment: What if a single User has been assigned to multiple sites?

Comment: I have to avoid the selection of site using GOTO in liferay.Redirect the user to  the appropriate site afte login.single site is assigned to every user,which is either communityA,B or C(for eg)

Answer (score 1):

### You have two options:

**1) You can set company.default.home.url property to a filter.**

Filter implements your logic to detect right page to send redirect.

This is a setting example:

*company.default.home.url=/landingPageFilter*

2) **Implements Liferay Default Landing Page** as described [here](https://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login) with this portal property

*login.events.post*